# Laravel 5.6. Route model bindung

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-resource

Hello I'm trying to create own laravel package it has two Controller resource, which have single controller and model `Post`

```
    Route::resource('posts', \vendor\package\Controllers\PostsController::class);
    Route::resource('categories', \vendor\package\Controllers\PostsController::class);
```

My method in the `PostsController` is `show(Post $post)`

If I open link http://localhost/posts/1, attributes element of `$post` is not empty in the `show` method.

But when I open link http://localhost/categories/1, attributes element of `$post` is empty.

How can I get Post data for `resource` `categories`?

P.S. difference between posts and categories is value of column `post_type` in the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define what the route parameter will be named for the generated routes when using resource routing.

This should be the only change you need to make:

```
Route::resource(
    'categories', 
    \vendor\package\Controllers\PostsController::class,
    ['parameters' => ['categories' => 'post']]
);
```

Now the route parameter is `post`:

```
GET categories/{post}
GET categories/{post}/edit
...
```

[Laravel 5.6 Docs - Controllers - Naming Resource Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)

Comment: Looks like works :) . Thanks. I have tried before set this parameter via maethod parameters() and it hasn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Add `Route::model('categories', App\Post::class);` to the `boot()` method in your

`./app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`

[source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#explicit-binding)

Comment: First I need to make it in custom package. But even I'm inserting to `RouteServiceProvider` not working

Comment: can you share the contents of how your `RouteServiceProvider` looks right now?

Comment: can you in your `PostsController` add a `dd($post)` inside the `show()` method? then open `http://localhost/posts/1` and `http://localhost/categories/1`, can you screenshot both?

Comment: categories - http://prntscr.com/kaqi2p, posts - http://prntscr.com/kaqiil

Comment: I have remarked that `connection: null` for categories

Comment: hmm, can you share the entire `show` method of your post controller to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176697/discussion-between-quezler-and-andrii).